# disperately trying to draw a line on the map

Tags: android, dictionary, paint

I'm reading some GPS data (longitude,latitude) from a ServerManager class that stores it.

The reading is done in a background thread AsyncTask and is done stept by step .Each time I get a new point I put it on the map and I waanna draw a line between it and the last point represented.

Here is a part of my code:

GeoPoint p;

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try {

        while (true) {
            longitude = Integer.parseInt(ServerManager.getInstance()
                    .getLastLongitude());
            latitude = Integer.parseInt(ServerManager.getInstance()
                    .getLastLatitude());
            Log.d("Date citite de threadul AsyncTask", " ");
            System.out.println(longitude);
            System.out.println(latitude);
            p = new GeoPoint(longitude, latitude);
            publishProgress(p);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(GeoPoint... progress1) {

    theRouteDraw(progress1[0]);
  geoPointsArray.add(progress1[0]);

  if (geoPointsArray.size() > 2) {
            int length = geoPointsArray.size();

            mapView.getOverlays().add(
                    new myOverlay(geoPointsArray.get(length - 1),
                            progress1[0]));
        }

}
```

### }

in order to represent the points on the map I use :

public void theRouteDraw(GeoPoint p1) {

```
mc.animateTo(p1);

mc.setZoom(17);

mapView.invalidate();

mapView.setSatellite(true);
```

}

---

And for obtaining an overlay I use:

class myOverlay extends Overlay {

```
    GeoPoint gp1;

    GeoPoint gp2;

    public myOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2) {

        this.gp1 = gp1;

        this.gp2 = gp2;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        Point from = new Point();

        projection.toPixels(gp1, from);

        Point to = new Point();

        projection.toPixels(gp2, to);

        canvas.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y, mPaint);


    }

}
```

My question:

Has anyone any clue why isn't any line drawn on my map????  Thank u:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
class myLocOverlay extends Overlay { public myLocOverlay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2) {
   this.gp1 = gp1;
this.gp2 = gp2;
}
```

and update your onDraw function with this

```
Paint paint = new Paint(); Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, point); Point point2 = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp2, point2); canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
```

you can add geopoint from you activity class

```
mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MyOverLay(startGP,endGP));
```

Comment: @adrian : if you are not getting any error message then check you overlay class and its draw function, check that whether they are calling properly. try using break point and check logcats